# Adding class to menu_class to wp_nav_menu adds class to div instead of ul

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I am very new to wordpress themeing . I am trying to create a `Twitter Bootstrap` menu to my newly created theme as below in `header.php` page.

```
$defaults = array(
                'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                'menu'            => '',
                'container'       => '',
                'container_class' => '',
                'container_id'    => '',
                'menu_class'      => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                'menu_id'         => 'navbar',
                'echo'            => true,
                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => '',
                'link_before'     => '',
                'link_after'      => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'           => 0,
                'walker'          => ''
            );

        wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

With the above codes, I am expecting to add a class to `navbar-collapse collapse` to `ul`, but instead it produces `HTML` as below :

`<div class="navbar-collapse collapse"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-11">` etc. How can I add class `ul` ?

Comment: Try to add classes to 'container_class' argument?

Comment: @Danijel I tried adding class there, not showing anywher :(

Answer (score 1):

Check you've actually registered 'header-menu' via [register_nav_menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). 
Removing theme_location => 'header-menu' will resolve the issue until you've registered your navigation ID correctly.

You should have this in your functions.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu', 'domain' ),
) );
```

Comment: I have added `function themeone_register_theme_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Main Navigation Menu' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'themeone_register_theme_menu' );` to functions.php . But still I am getting the same result !

Comment: 'primary' is the theme_location attribute, you're calling 'header-menu' in your first example. See my solution for what you should have.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out a function that's already been made [like this one](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker). It will create the correct syntax for the menu to work.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that no one solved your problem. I want to provide a solution for future users. The solution is in the container parameter of the wp_nav_menu function.

Documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

> - container string - Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with.
>   Default 'div'.

To make parameter menu_class add it`s valuse to correct element, in your case it is ul element, you have to define container parameter as div, like below. Then parameter container_class will have default class 'menu-{menu slug}-container' because it`s not have any value given. container_id parameter also will be empty becouse there is no value given.

```html
$defaults = array(
'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
'container'     => 'div',
'container_class'   => '',
'container_id'      => '',
'menu_id'       => 'navbar',
'menu_class'        => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
);

        wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Then menu_class and menu_id parameters will be added to the ul element and ul element will look this `<ul id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">`.

In case you don`t want to have div container delete container_class and container_id and leave container parameter with ul value like this:

```html
'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
'container'     => 'ul',                                    
'menu_id'       => 'navbar',
'menu_class'        => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
```